# WPF TabItem HeaderTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Sample code:

```
 <TabControl>
    <TabItem>
        <TabItem.Header>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5">
                <Image Source="/WpfTutorialSamples;component/Images/bullet_blue.png" />
                <TextBlock Text="Blue" Foreground="Blue" />
            </StackPanel>
        </TabItem.Header>
        <Label Content="Content goes here..." />
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem>
        <TabItem.Header>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5">
                <TextBlock Text="Red" Foreground="Red" />
            </StackPanel>
        </TabItem.Header>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem>
        <TabItem.Header>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5">
                <Rectangle Fill="Red" width="20" height="16" />
            </StackPanel>
        </TabItem.Header>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

As you can see, the TabItem Header is Always a stackpanel with different content:

```
<TabItem.Header>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5">

    </StackPanel>
</TabItem.Header>
```

How can you put this in a template so that I don't have duplicate stackpanel code?

Trying to do it like this:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
        <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5">
                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}"
                            ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentStringFormat}"  
                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentTemplate}" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                            RecognizesAccessKey="True" 
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}"  
                            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.VerticalContentAlignment}">
                </ContentPresenter>
            </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.Resources>
    <TabItem>
        <TabItem.Header>
            <!-- ??? -->
            <TextBlock Text="X" />
            <TextBlock Text="Y" />
        </TabItem.Header>
</TabControl>
```

results in:

- "The property 'Header' is set more than once."
- "The object 'Object' already has a child and cannot add 'TextBlock'. 'Object' can accept only one child."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only thing the tree headers really have common is the Margin="5". In second and third tab the stackpanel is irrelavant, because it has only one child. You can achive it either by using HeaderTemplate or ItemContainerStyle:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>

    <TabItem>
        <TabItem.Header>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="/WpfTutorialSamples;component/Images/bullet_blue.png" />
                <TextBlock Text="Blue" Foreground="Blue" />
            </StackPanel>
        </TabItem.Header>
        <Label Content="Content goes here..." />
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem>
        <TabItem.Header>
            <TextBlock Text="Red" Foreground="Red" />
        </TabItem.Header>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem>
        <TabItem.Header>
            <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="20" Height="16" />
        </TabItem.Header>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

now you don't repeat anything.

You could also extract the properties of stackpanel to style to avoid repeating them:

```
    <TabItem.Header>
        <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource TabHeaderPanel}">
            <Image Source="/WpfTutorialSamples;component/Images/bullet_blue.png" />
            <TextBlock Text="Blue" Foreground="Blue" />
        </StackPanel>
    </TabItem.Header>

    <TabItem.Header>
        <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource TabHeaderPanel}">
            <TextBlock Text="Red" Foreground="Red" />
        </StackPanel>
    </TabItem.Header>

    <TabItem.Header>
        <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource TabHeaderPanel}">
            <Rectangle Fill="Red" width="20" height="16" />
        </StackPanel>
    </TabItem.Header>
```

If you want even more code reuse, you should consider MVVM-like approach:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}">
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="local:TabViewModel">

                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5">
                            <Image x:Name="Icon" Source="{Binding Icon, Converter={StaticResource UriToBitmapSourceConverter}}" />
                            <Rectangle x:Name="ColorRect" Height="16" Width="16" Fill="{Binding Color}" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="{Binding Color}"/>
                        </StackPanel>

                        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Icon}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                <Setter TargetName="Icon" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                <Setter TargetName="ColorRect" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</TabControl>
```

if you can't use single DataTemplate for all headers, you can use `HeaderTemplateSelector`

Comment: Thanks, i can't bind my tabs as they are not dynamic content and it would be overkill jus to create a viewmodel for something fixed.
 "tree headers really have common is the Margin="5", wel not really the stackpanel makes sure that the tabitem headers have the same hight. if you play with verticalalignment you will see that some tabs seem to ignore it for some specific cases. So i need the stackpanel (have been testing it several times)

Comment: You do not need StackPanel to ensure the same Height of all tab headers. The problem is somewhere else, but that should be asked in different question. However you should be able to specify height in ItemContainerStyle

Answer (score 0):

I think HeaderTemplate will only be used if you are binding the Tab collection and generating them dynamically. This would work if you set your objects in a ViewModel (Header property is a collection of items that with implicit DataTemplates, could generate TextBlocks or Rectangles depending on their types).

Otherwise, you would either need to give your `StackPanel`s common styling to make them all identical and save repetition, or set the first element of the `TabItem.Header` content to a custom control that derives from `StackPanel`.

I would choose the Style route myself, unless there is a really pressing need to remove even the StackPanel line from your XAML.